# Does this php code secure me from SQL injection and XSS?

Tags: php, sql-injection, xss

I have sanitize class that I run before anything else on every page of my site. I'm pretty sure addslashes is the same as escaping with mysql_real_escape_string heres the class.

```
class sanatize
{
private static $singleton;

function __construct(){

    $_CLEAN_POST = array();
    $_CLEAN_GET = array();
    $_CLEAN_REQUEST = array();

    foreach($_REQUEST as $key => $value)
    {
        $key = addslashes(trim(strip_tags($key)));
        $value = addslashes(trim(strip_tags($value)));

        $_CLEAN_REQUEST[$key] = $value;
    }
    foreach($_GET as $key => $value)
    {
        $key = addslashes(trim(strip_tags($key)));
        $value = addslashes(trim(strip_tags($value)));

        $_CLEAN_GET[$key] = $value;
    }
    foreach($_POST as $key => $value)
    {
        if(is_array($value)){
            foreach($value as $key2 => $value2){

                $key2 = addslashes(trim(strip_tags($key2)));
                $value2 = addslashes(trim(strip_tags($value2)));

                $_CLEAN_POST[$key][$key2] = $value2;
            }
        }
        else{
            $key = addslashes(trim(strip_tags($key)));
            $value = addslashes(trim(strip_tags($value)));

            $_CLEAN_POST[$key] = $value;
        }
    }
    $_POST = array();
    $_GET = array();
    $_REQUEST = array();

    $_POST = $_CLEAN_POST;
    $_GET = $_CLEAN_GET;
    $_REQUEST = $_CLEAN_REQUEST;
}
function __destruct()
{
    //echo "cleaned";
}

public static function getInstance()
{
    if(is_null(self::$singleton))
    {
        self::$singleton = new sanatize();
    }
    return self::$singleton;
}
}
```

and then i'll call it using

```
$sanatize = sanatize::getInstance();
```

Comment: `addslashes()` doesn't work the same way as `mysql_real_escape_string()`

Comment: This is just a bad idea all around. It's not equivalent to mysql_real_escape_string, and you don't want to add slashes to every variable in every request -- they're not all going into database queries, and you may want to alter or display some of those values.

Comment: @stillstanding could you elaborate?

Comment: http://shiflett.org/blog/2006/jan/addslashes-versus-mysql-real-escape-string

Answer (score 7, accepted):

"I'm pretty sure addslashes is the same as escaping with mysql_real_escape_string heres the class."

First, it's not.  `mysql_real_escape_string` is aware of the connection, and takes that connection's character set into account.

Second, you're basically replicating the failed [`magic_quotes`](http://php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.php) design.  Not all of those fields are going into the database, so you're doing unnecessary work.  You also have to be careful never to re-escape something in a "clean" array; double-escaping is a very common problem.

In my opinion, the simplest solution to SQL injection is prepared statements.  I recommend using either [`PDO`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) or [`mysqli`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php).

EDIT: Since you're already using mysqli, you should forget about this CLEAN idea, and simply use [`MySQLi_STMT`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli-stmt.php).  [`mysqli::prepare`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php) gives an example of how to create and bind variables to a prepared statement.  Note the `?` place-holder.  Also look at [`mysqli_stmt::bind_param`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php).